# Star Rating Eventhandlers

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How can I change the star rating and make it to default when I click outside the elements?

Also, for instance if I click to the 4th star I have the first 4 stars on red, but if I click again to the second one I should only get first and second on red and get third and fourth on previous color blue.

```
let stars=document.querySelector(".hearts").children;

for(let i = 0; i<stars.length; i++){
    stars[i].onmouseover =  funcion;
    stars[i].onmouseout = funcionn;
    stars[i].addEventListener('click', funcio3);



    function funcion (){
        for(let j= 0; j<=i; j++){
            stars[j].classList.remove('fa-heart');
            stars[j].classList.add('fa-w-16');
        }
    };

    function funcionn (){
        for(let j= 0; j<=i; j++){
            stars[j].classList.remove('fa-w-16');
            stars[j].classList.add('fa-heart');
        }

    };

    function funcio3 (){
        for(let j= 0; j<=i; j++){
            stars[j].style.color = 'red';
        }

    };




};
```

Answer (score 0):

- To catch a click outside the element you need to listen to click event on the document and check that the target isn't a start.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', evt => {
    if (!evt.target.closest('.hearts')) {
        // click has been fired outside .hearts children
    }
});
```

- In your 'funcio3' you need to first reset the color of all starts before adding the color red.